# Is there MPI stub library?

Tags: mpi

I have C source with MPI calls.

I wonder can I get sequential program from the source by linking with some MPI stub library? Where can I get this lib?

Comment: It's not an answer because it is not finished, but https://github.com/MPILander/MPILander aspires to be a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most correctly-written MPI programs should not depend on the number of processes they use to get a correct answer -- eg, if you run them on one process (mpirun -np 1 ./a.out) they should still work.   So you oughtn't need a stub library - just use MPI.    (If for some reason you just don't want extraneous libraries kicking around, it's certainly *possible* to write stubs and link against them -- I did this back in the day when setting up MPI on my laptop was a huge PITA, you could use [this](http://www.cita.utoronto.ca/~ljdursi/code/mpinull.tgz) as a starting point and add any functionality you need.   But these days, fiddling with the stub library is probably going to be more work than just using an existing MPI implementation.)

If your MPI program does *not* currently work correctly on one processor, a stub library probably won't help; you'll need to find the special cases that it's not handling and fix them.

Comment: The keyword is "most"...it is certainly possible to design a correct MPI program that relies on having multiple ranks - hopefully that is "by design" and not an "accident" of the programming.  Perhaps Rank 0 hands out work and collects results, but does no actual work itself - in such cases one would hope for a guard in the code to prevent running with fewer than the minimum required ranks.  I agree that replacing MPI with stubs would be a huge PITA.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible. Contrary to OpenMP, programs using MPI don't necessarily run or produce the same result when you simply take away the MPI part.

Comment: Stubs rarely produce the same results as the full implementation anyway, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: The way I understand the question, the OP wants to get a sequential, fully running program.

Answer (score 0):

PETSc contains a stub MPI library that works for one process (ie serial) execution:
http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-3.2/include/mpiuni/mpi.h

Comment: Did you find the PETSc stub MPI library? It's not obvious to me, so a link would be appreciated.